# How to get a particular string from curl json output

Tags: curl, jq, jira-rest-api

I'm performing the following curl command against Jira api:

> issue_key=$(curl -g -D- -X GET -H "Content-Type: application/json"
>   "http://real_path/rest/api/2/search?jql=cf[10804]~${real_value}&maxResults=2&fields=id,key"
>   -u "test_user:test_pass")

I'm doing that in order to receive the Jira issue key which matches the specific value of a custom field(cf[10804]).

The response to my curl request is as follows:

```
HTTP/1.1 200
X-AREQUESTID: 674x690471x1
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'self'
X-ASEN: SEN-389841
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=blabla; Path=/; HttpOnly
X-Seraph-LoginReason: OK
Set-Cookie: blablab; Path=/
X-ASESSIONID: zffx7a
X-AUSERNAME: test_user
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, no-transform
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Tue, 26 Nov 2019 09:14:29 GMT

{"expand":"names,schema","startAt":0,"maxResults":2,"total":1,"issues":[{"expand":"operations,versionedRepresentations,editmeta,changelog,renderedFields","id":"574719","self":"real_path/rest/api/2/issue/574719","key":"test_project-4044"}]}
```

However, I would like to receive from the curl only the following value(appears at the end of the response, under "key" within the JSON response part): test_project-4044

May someone help me with that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is your friend (for this and many other json tricks):

You don't need `-D` nor `-X` passed to curl. I presume you still need that `-H` option.

A fixed command line could look like:

`curl -g -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http://real_path/rest/api/2/search?jql=cf[10804]~${real_value}&maxResults=2&fields=id,key" -u "test_user:test_pass") | jq -r '.issues[0].key'`

Given the example json from your question, passed to `jq -r '.issues[0].key'`, it produces the following output:

```
test_project-4044
```