# Issues search error: Unexpected character (''' (code <N>)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to get this same type of query.

```bash
curl -u admin:admin -X POST localhost:50813/rest/api/2/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jql":"updated > -1d","fields":[""]}' -s | jq > jql-output.txt
```

But hitting error.
I ref this query from
https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-programmatically-update-issues-from-a-jql-using-rest-api-in-jira-1031284474.html

Error which I am getting for now is to debug further.

```bash
curl -u admin:admin -X POST localhost:50813/rest/api/2/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jql":"updated > -1d","fields":[""]}'
```

Error:

> {"errorMessages":["Unexpected character (''' (code 39)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@c502a0b; line: 1, column: 2]"]}

Any idea? Been trying various options. No clear solution

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems this is a documentation error. You can basically remove the `fields` from request (and it returns all fields as default) or you can set it from one of the following as stated in [another Jira documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/9.2.1/#api/2/search-searchUsingSearchRequest):

> By default, only navigable (*navigable) fields are returned in this
> search resource. Note: the default is different in the get-issue
> resource -- the default there all fields (*all).
>
> ```
> *all - include all fields
> *navigable - include just navigable fields
> summary,comment - include just the summary and comments
> -description - include navigable fields except the description (the default is *navigable for search)
> *all,-comment - include everything except comments
> ```

So basically, the request is should be like that:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST localhost:50813/rest/api/2/search -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"jql":"updated > -1d"}'
```

Comment: I tried without "fields" option. Error is still same. no luck still. ie. as you mentioned.

Comment: Found this below link helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047584/how-to-get-a-particular-string-from-curl-json-output?rq=1  able to use this logic to extract and do some tweaking to get key details.